# Can't enable Flash in Firefox on Windows

Tags: firefox, flash

I'm trying to go to Flash website (it works in Chrome).

Firefox is redirecting me to [an enable page](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/enable-adobe-flash-player) which redirects me to [download](http://forum.thewindowsclub.com/windows-security/35700-adobe-flash-player-direct-download-links.html) of not found file: http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/get/flashplayer/current/licensing/win/install_flash_player_12_plugin.exe

I didn't find a Flash add on that could help. Can I view Flash in Firefox?

I know for a fact that people still uses Flash sites in Firefox. How can I enable it too?

Comment: see https://blog.mozilla.org/futurereleases/2017/07/25/firefox-roadmap-flash-end-life/ for the long plot.

Comment: The issue I know for a fact that people still uses Flash site in Firefox, how can I still use it too?

Comment: Can't help on that, sorry. Haven't allowed Flash anywhere in the building for over a year.

Comment: https://www.wired.com/story/adobe-finally-kills-flash-dead/